# python openpyxl set cursor on the chosen cell

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlsx

I'm using `openpyxl` library to do some excel cut/paste operations on spreadsheets. 
Let's say that my operations produce the following data (please use it for reproducibility purposes):

```
col1;col2
1;0,17153686
2;0,615324797
3;0,573701744
4;0,503462355
5;0,154284926
6;0,10027259
7;0,926526263
8;0,871108863
9;0,048035143
10;0,38731583
11;0,48529708
12;0,901046699
13;0,985505734
14;0,606868435
15;0,280662943
16;0,356188065
17;0,102727139
18;0,800757985
19;0,767509347
20;0,418477445
21;0,751892035
22;0,959923786
23;0,524754643
24;0,014140778
25;0,267427799
26;0,666726192
27;0,019314009
28;0,764133187
29;0,587031993
```

This is the code that chooses the active cell according to an argument given:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook, Workbook

def set_active_cell(new_file_name, active_row):
    print(active_row)
    workbook = load_workbook(new_file_name)
    sheet = workbook.get_sheet_names()[0] #get the name of first sheet
    worksheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name(sheet)
    coords = "A" + str(active_row)
    print(coords)
    # worksheet.cell(row=active_row, column=1)
    worksheet.sheet_view.selection[0].activeCell = coords
    worksheet.sheet_view.selection[0].sqref = coords
    workbook.save(new_file_name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    set_active_cell("data.xlsx", 28)
```

As you can see on the attached image my default view encompasses the first 18 rows. If `active_row` is smaller or equal to 18 I get what I want: I can see the active cell in my starting view of the Excel file.

[image]

However, any `active_row`'s value greater than 18 results in the problem. The active cell is chosen correctly, but my starting view is still the first 18 rows and I need to scroll down in order the reach the active cell.

Is there any way to change the view with using `openpyxl`?

Comment: This code will change the view in a worksheet and set the active cell. It's possible you're expecting something else? In any case the worksheet lookup is a big fragile.

Comment: I expect that code changes the cell. The view changes based on the coordinates of the active cell. That's all what I expect from my code and `openpyxl` :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scrolling is done by adjusting the openpyxl.worksheet.views.SheetView.**topLeftCell** variable.

You can scroll to your `coords` variable with:

```
worksheet.sheet_view.topLeftCell = coords
```

You can find more details in the [openpyxl documentation.](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.views.html)

Answer (score 2):

With openpyxl **2.6.2** you have to set `activeCell` and `sqref` like this:

```
ws.views.sheetView[0].selection[0].activeCell = 'B15'
ws.views.sheetView[0].selection[0].sqref = 'B15'
```